# What kind of warnings is -isystem in gcc supposed to ignore?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, cflags

Several blogs, tutorials and GCC's documentation have lead me to believe `-isystem` can be used to ignore warnings in header files. A simple test suggests otherwise.

```
#include <liburing.h>

int main() { return 0; }
```

Compiled as:

```
~ > gcc -isystem /opt/extras/include -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -std=c89 -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors test.c

/opt/extras/include/liburing.h:140:14: error: expected ';' before 'void'
  140 | static inline void io_uring_cq_advance(struct io_uring *ring,
      |              ^~~~~
      |              ;
In file included from /opt/extras/include/liburing/barrier.h:56,
                 from /opt/extras/include/liburing.h:16,
                 from test.c:1:
/opt/extras/include/liburing.h: In function 'io_uring_cq_advance':
/opt/extras/include/liburing.h:150:3: error: unknown type name 'typeof'
  150 |   io_uring_smp_store_release(cq->khead, *cq->khead + nr);
```

The documentation for [`-isystem`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) and [System-Headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html) isn't exactly clear about what kind of warnings in system headers it is supposed to ignore. Why does GCC not ignore pendantic warnings/errors in 3rd party headers which is explictly marked as `-isystem`?

To put some perspective, the coding guidelines I'm following enforces strict ANSI C for "business" reasons, which I cannot change. For now, I've edited that header by replacing `inline` to `__inline` and `typeof` to `__typeof` which seems to work.

Comment: Note that the compiler output shown is reporting errors *not* warnings.

Comment: These are errors.

Comment: If by "work" you mean "successfully evade the guidelines", then yes, this works. Under C89 aka ISO/IEC 9899:1990, which is *a former standard*, `__inline` and `__typeof` are exactly as non-standard as `inline` and `typeof`. *The standard*, which is ISO/IEC 9899:2018 at this moment, has `inline` but no `__inline`, `typeof` or `__typeof`.

Comment: @G.M. `static inline` and `typeof` are both GNUisms and not *syntax errors*. And since it's marked `-isystem` it shouldn't report these as errors when compiling _my_ code.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I am not evading standards in _my_ code here :) Older versions of libpcap would error in `-std=c89` too. But having `pcap.h` in `-isystem` supresses those errors. Which leads to the other question, what kind of errors/warnings is `-isystem` supposed to supress? Where does GCC draw the line?

Comment: GNUisms or not, the compiler, as invoked, considers them to be errors and compilation cannot succeed with errors.  Please see the answer by @dbush .

Comment: It is supposed to suppress all warnings, and no errors. Note that `inline` is not known to c89, so you get an error when you compile with -std=c89. Note also that if you request `-pedantic-errors`, then you get pedantic errors, not pedantic warnings.

Comment: It seems you want gcc to suppress errors if they are treated as warnings or not diagnosed at all in *some other* compilation mode. But gcc doesn't work this way.

Comment: Re “pendantic warnings/errors”: Those are not pedantic errors, they are fundamental parsing problems.

Answer (score 2):

The special treatment given to system header files is to ignore any *warnings* in the header, as mentioned in the second link you gave:

> All warnings, other than those generated by ‘#warning’ (see Diagnostics), are suppressed while GCC is processing a system header

The problem is that you're getting errors, not warnings.  The header apparently uses features that are not allowed in strictly conforming C89.

That means you're stuck modifying the header to use compiler-specific extensions, however I wouldn't depend on doing such things.  This would be a good case to push for an exception to the guidelines since the library in question doesn't strictly conform to C89.

Comment: I'd argue that `static inline` and `typeof` are GNUisms in 3rd party headers and not valid syntax errors in _my_ code. And it therefore doesn't warrant throwing errors in my code.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer Errors are errors, and code won't compile with errors.  So you need to either get rid of strict conformance or use libraries that are strictly C89 compliant.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer: Re “I'd argue that static inline and typeof are GNUisms in 3rd party headers and not valid syntax errors in *my* code”: What is your premise here, that there exists some variant of C in which these are keywords and the compiler ought to recognize them as keywords while compiling a variant of C in which they are not keywords? How can that work? The compiler should know of all variants and accept their keywords? Even if it did that, C89 code is allowed to use `inline` and `typeof` for variables and other things…

Comment: … So now you have a situation where a program might include this header you want, and the compiler has to figure out to ignore `inline` there, but the code later has `int inline = 0;`, and the compiler has to figure out it is a variable there, not a keyword from some other language variant. That is unworkable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the latest version of liburing.h
https://github.com/axboe/liburing/blob/master/src/include/liburing.h

This seems to declare the io_uring_cq_advance() differently.

Comment: I've tried with the latest code as well. The keywords are still there and I still get the same errors (in different lines).